Find the number of order triples (x, y, z) of integers?
Question:
Find the number of order triples x, y, z of integers such $that
$x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2-2y^2z^2-2z^2x^2=24$

My try:
$(x^2-y^2-z^2)^2=x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2+2y^2z^2-2x^2z^2$
So, $x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2-2y^2z^2-2z^2x^2=(x^2-y^2-z^2)^2-4y^2z^2=(x^2-y^2-z^2+2yz)(x^2-y^2-z^2-2yz)$
After this I can't solve it. Please tell me if you can solve it the same way I did or another faster method.

We can still factorize the polynomial further, and obtain
$$
 (x + y + z)(x + y - z)(x - y + z)(x - y - z)=24.
$$
Now $24$ has $8$ divisors, namely $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24$.

Oh ok, thanks a ton.
